# Medium Editor not pre-filling value in VueJS directive

Tags: vue.js, medium-editor

I am attempting to integrate the medium editor with a VueJs directive.

It is working well but the initial `value` prop for the field is not initially populating the medium editor. As soon as I update the text in the medium editor the link is established and the html is populated in the textarea.

**Directive:**

```
Vue.directive('wysiwyg', {
  bind () {
    let editor = new MediumEditor(this.el)
  }
})
```

**Element:**

```
<textarea v-wysiwyg name="{{ name }}" class="wysiwyg">{{ value }}</textarea>
```

It appears that the bind function runs before the value is populated in the `textarea`.

Anyone had any experience integrating these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a bind on the container will happen before the binding of its contents. You can wait for it by using [`nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-nextTick).

```js
Vue.directive('wysiwyg', {
  bind() {
    Vue.nextTick(() => new MediumEditor(this.el));
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    value: 'Initial text'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/medium-editor/5.22.0/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/medium-editor/5.22.0/css/medium-editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<textarea v-wysiwyg name="{{ name }}" class="wysiwyg">{{ value }}</textarea>
```

Comment: Spot on! That is exactly what I was after!